# How to use Invoke-RestMethod with Import-Csv to loop through URLs

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet, windows-terminal, invoke-restmethod

I'm attempting to dynamically create about 50 QR Codes using [GoQR.me's API](https://goqr.me/api/doc/create-qr-code/). I have all the source and destination URLs in a CSV file QRCodes.csv formatted as:

```
source, destination
https://api.qrservers.com/v1/..., C:\Users\...\QR1.png
```

I originally attempted to use PowerShell's `Start-BitsTransfer`

```
Import-Csv QRCodes.csv | Start-BitsTransfer
```

But because the server doesn't return Content-Length in the header of the HTTP reply, Start-BitsTransfer fails.

How would I do something similar using `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebReqest` instead? I can easily do one request at a time, but can't figure out how to loop through the CSV. (I'm a relative noob at PowerShell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the `source` cell contains all the data required by the API endpoint, use `ForEach-Object` to iterate over the list of CSV records and then call `Invoke-WebRequest`:

```
Import-Csv QRCodes.csv | ForEach-Object {
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.source -OutFile $_.destination
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! Thank you. It worked perfectly.